# unknown error creating user with firebase

Tags: authentication, firebase

I am receiving a CORS error from my browser while trying to implement a simple login authentication (email/password) with firebase.

I checked the security rules and it is set to

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
 }
}
```

Here's a summary of my code from the example.

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.5.0/firebase-simple-login.js'> </script>


var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://vivid-fire-myserver.firebaseio.com/');
var authClient = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myRootRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        alert(error);
        return;
    }
    if (user) {
        alert('user already logged in');
    } else {
        alert('user logged out');
    }
});

$("#registerButton").on("click", function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    authClient.createUser(email, password, function(error,  user) {
        if (!error) {
            alert('registered successfully');
        } else {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the network log?

Comment: Seems like it is a cross origin error, not exactly sure how to fix it though:  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://auth.firebase.com/auth/firebase/create?email=asdf%40gmail.com&password=asdfasdf&firebase=vivid-fire-3819. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: Is it because the scripts are calling https://cdn.firebase.com/... and https://auth.firebase.com/... ?

Comment: Firebase use a fully-permissive / wildcard CORS policy. What browser / version are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: I'm using the latest firefox and chrome and they both fail the same way.  After a bit of hacking, I finally zeroed in on the problem.  I am not sure why this caused the CORS error, but I created the following basic form with and without the type="button" and it would fail/succeed.  For some reason, it needed the type="button" declared or it would throw the CORS error....do you know why it would cause this?

<form>
    <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
    <button type="button" id="myButton"> press me </button>
</form>

Comment: Glad you got it working, but that error is bizarre. Can you send over the before and after code to me personally so I can investigate? (rob at firebase dot com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55452/discussion-between-rob-dimarco-and-swoosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is a result of submitting my form, which causes the page to reload.  As confirmed with Rob, "the reload is taking place before the HTTP OPTIONS request to the server checking the CORS configuration is able to complete.

A work around is to prevent the form from reloading upon submission.  I did this by returning false in my html form and my jquery scripts.

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" onSubmit="return goLogin()">
..........

function goLogin() {
    $("#loginButton").click(function() {
    ......      
    )}; 

    return false;   
}
```